# Inserting mock data into an associative table in SQL with a composite key

Tags: sql, database, xampp, primary-key, composite-key

long time lurker first time poster!

I am working on a SQL database to go with my web-application. I have two associative tables to connect many-to-many relationships. I am using Mockaroo to generate mock data for my tables as needed then I came to my associative table.

The schema I have now looks as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
dirtId INT NOT NULL,
lightId INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (dirtId, lightId),
FOREIGN KEY (dirtId) REFERENCES Dirts (id),
FOREIGN KEY (lightId) REFERENCES Lights (id)
);
```

I am trying to figure out how to generate mock data for my primary keys, or even the format for the INSERT statement when using a composite key like this.

For my foreign keys I don't see a problem with just having random ints within the values in the other table populate it but I am not sure of the syntax or the way to use mockaroo to accomplish this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Easy example which uses CTE.

```
;with tbl as (
select 1 id
union all
select id+1
from tbl where id<10
)
--insert myTable
select t1.id dirtId, t2.id lightId
from tbl t1 cross join tbl t2
```

If your DBMS doesn't support CTE then another solution.

```
create table #tbl (id int)
declare @id int = 1
while @id < 11
begin
insert #tbl values(@id)
set @id += 1
end
--insert myTable
select t1.id dirtId, t2.id lightId
from #tbl t1 cross join #tbl t2
--drop table #tbl
```

Or if you have something in `Dirts` and `Lights` then use them in the same way.